# How to find the regression of a given input in java?

Tags: java, math

I have a two array inputs of data. Call them p and t. I need to find the regression function of these columns so I can accuratly predict future values. Is there any way to do this with in java? If so, what is the best way?

Comment: You mean are there any existing Java statistics libraries that will do this for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of:
[apache commons math](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.0/index.html) (see stat.regression).